# Update multiple tables with same structure using array or cursor?

Tags: foxpro

Using VFP 6.0...  I am trying to see if I can update multiple tables using data fields from an array or cursor.  So for example I would create a cursor and append data from a txt file to it:

```
create cursor cTemp(acct c(5), field c(5), newscript c(25))
append from file delimited with tab
```

...Now I want to set up a loop that would use the 1st field (acct) to seek out the table, then update the table using the field & newscript from the cursor.  I am having trouble using field to be used as a field name in an update command:

```
UPDATE acct\table SET &field = newscript
```

Since the field will change depending on the acct\table, I need it to be flexible in the script.

Comment: can you show some sample data of what this cursor will contain for the applicable updates you are attempting?  It SOUNDs like you want to dynamically both pick the table, and pick the column name OF THAT table to be updated, and the SCRIPT has some criteria behind it more.

Answer (score 1):

you first need to use a memory variable (not a field from a table) to use the macro expansion "&".
so start off with: `f_name=field(1)` to capture the first field of the table into a variable.
Then do your loop around `UPDATE table SET &f_name = value`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Cursor cTemp(acct c(5), Field c(5), newscript c(25))
Append From myfile Delimited With Tab

Select cTemp

Scan

* -- Copy values of current record to an object.
    Scatter Name loThis

    * -- Assumes target table is already open. If not add code to open it.
    * -- Also assumes you want to update all records in target table.
    Replace All (loThis.Field) With loThis.newscript In (loThis.acct)

Endscan
```

Comment: There will only be 1 field updated per acct.   The table structure is exactly the same for each acct, but the field to be updated with vary.

Answer (score 0):

> It is difficult to tell exactly what you mean by UPDATE acct\table... I make the assumption that each table is called "table" but the "acct" is the folder. In my example, you will have c:\tmp\t1\ctable, c:\tmp\t2\ctable,c:\tmp\t3\ctable (BTW, it is not cool to use reserved words like TABLE and FIELD for things like table names and field names).

If you have a c:\tmp set up, you can run this code as is. You will end up changing each table's 1 record that contains "xxxxx" to the data listed in the cursor records.

```
* I have a tmp folder. In it I created 3 subfolders: t1, t2, t3.
set default to c:\tmp
* All tables are the same name (ctable). First table in folder t1 with field name cf10
create table t1\ctable (cf10 c(25))
* Insert a record with "xxxxx" as the data
insert into ctable values ("xxxxx")
* this will show you what is in the table. escape to let the program run.
brow last
use

* 2nd table, field is called cf8.
create table t2\ctable (cf8 c(25))
insert into ctable values ("xxxxx")
brow last
use

* 3rd table, field is called cf6
create table t3\ctable (cf6 c(25))
insert into ctable values ("xxxxx")
brow last
use

* create cursor, add 3 records (this is just for testing... this would be like your appending of the text file).
create cursor cTemp(acct c(5), cfield c(5), newscript c(25))
insert into ctemp values ("t1","cf10","data for field10")
insert into ctemp values ("t2","cf8","data for field8")
insert into ctemp values ("t3","cf6","data for field6")
* so I am telling the cursor to update unique field names in a table called CTABLE with unique data
scan
    m.lcExecString="UPDATE " + alltrim(acct)+"\ctable SET "+cfield+"='"+alltrim(newscript)+"'"
    &lcExecString
    select ctable
    browse last
    * make sure to close the file you are updating
    use in select("ctable")
endscan
```